# C language printf output a NULL pointer

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
   char *ret = NULL;

   printf("ret: %s\n", ret);
   printf("%s\n", ret);

   return(0);
}


ret: (null)
Segmentation fault
```

The outputs are different, the result should be "segmentation fault", since ret points to nothing!

Why it outputs "(null)" when I just add "ret:" in printf()?

Comment: Because you have made it point to `NULL`

Comment: If the format string is **exactly** `"%s\n"`, `gcc` optimizes the whole thing to `puts()`. See linked duplicate for details.

Comment: "the result should be "segmentation fault"," --> No, it is _undefined_ what happens in this case.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks @chux